# Looking for group theory of radix reversal involutions?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, fast-fourier-transform

From an applied maths background, I'm familiar with (binary) bit-reversal involutions and more generally, radix-reversal involutions when using a mixed-radix counting system.

I've become interested in these from a pure maths viewpoint, but haven't been able to find much on their group theory. Even simple questions such as  'what subgroups of symmetric groups do they generate'?

There's plenty of literature on them in applied maths & computer science due to their use in Fast Fourier Transforms, but I'm looking for pointers  to their pure group theory. I'm sure this must have been well-studied, so any decent references will be well-appreciated :)

Edited to add, thanks for the replies!  To be more precise about the 'subgroups of symmetric groups' question, this is what I'm looking at :

Given some non-prime natural number N, along with an ordered factorisation N = a_1a_2..a_k (not necessarily a prime factorisation), we can write each natural number between 0 and N-1 using the a_1 a_2 .. a_k radix counting system, and derive an involution by radix reversal.  Given a different ordered factorisation, we derive a different involution on the same set of naturals.  I'm interesting in characterising the subgroup of the symmetric group on {0,..,N-1} that these involutions generate.

Comment: I'm not qualified to answer but it's interesting and I'd like to clarify some ideas for my own benefit, if I may. Digit reversal means 368 maps to 863, eg ? Then the group is F_2, acting on Z ?

Comment: That's exactly the idea. In binary, 1101 maps to 1011, in hexadecimal 0FEE maps to EEF0 and similar.  What I'm looking for is the general case, where you use a mixed-radix counting system.

Comment: I suppose the group is always F_2, even in the mixed radix case, but its action on Z might be more interesting in that general case ?

Comment: If all elements except the identity are involutions then it's commutative. If the group is finite this means it's some finite direct product of $Z_2$.

Comment: One thing to think about might be in what ways could the problem be more interesting, provided one takes into account the algebraic structure of Z, than if one simply treats integers as sequences of symbols (their expansion wrt some sequence of radices).